# 404 error when trying to reach a defined route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm getting a 404 error for a search route despite similarly defined routes working fine. I'm trying to search for a post via its title and/or tags. Here are my routes defined in the backend:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getPosts);
router.get("/:id", getPost);
router.get("/search", getPostsBySearch);
router.post("/", auth, createPost);
router.patch("/:id", auth, updatePost);
router.patch("/:id/likePost", auth, likePost);
router.delete("/:id", auth, deletePost);

export default router
```

Here is my action for searching for a post:

```
export const getPostsBySearch = (searchQuery) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: "START_LOADING" });
    const { data } = await api.fetchPostsBySearch(searchQuery);
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_BY_SEARCH", payload: data });
    dispatch({ type: "END_LOADING" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

And here is the api file exporting routes to the action:

```
const API = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:5000" });

export const fetchPosts = (page) => API.get(`/posts?page=${page}`);
export const fetchPost = (id) => API.get(`/posts/${id}`);
export const fetchPostsBySearch = (searchQuery) =>
  API.get(
    `/posts/search?searchQuery=${searchQuery.search || "none"}&tags=${
      searchQuery.tags
    }`
  );
```

Comment: I don't see any route with /posts defined. How do you intent to route there?

Comment: If those routes are the posts routes and you are sure that you included `/posts` when using them in your express app, you should first try it on `postman` to see if you get a response.

Comment: I set up the routes to use '/posts' in my server index file which is why I didn't include posts in the route file. All of those other routes work except the search for some reason. Also, very sorry for the very late reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/search", getPostsBySearch); // Route you mentioned
but you were using `/posts/search`

export const fetchPostsBySearch = (searchQuery) =>
  API.get(
    `/search?searchQuery=${searchQuery.search || "none"}&tags=${
      searchQuery.tags
    }`
  );
```

Comment: I'm using /posts in my server index file which I had neglected to mention. All the other routes work with /posts being used as well, it's just this search not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the :id route on top of the search route, so it was reading /search as an id, so instead of

```
router.get("/", getPosts);
router.get("/:id", getPost);
router.get("/search", getPostsBySearch);
```

it should be

```
router.get("/", getPosts);
router.get("/search", getPostsBySearch);
router.get("/:id", getPost);
```